# Does pouncing from ceiling also deal fall damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, wild-shape

One of my players is a 8th level druid. He favours wild shaping into a tiger. He cast *spider climb* and walked up/onto the ceiling which was 30 feet high using the wall. He then wanted to use his special attack, pounce, from the ceiling, onto an enemy.

Now I had no problems with him using pounce in this fashion, but the player wanted to deal falling damage on top of the pounce attack.

At the time I was not familiar with the [falling damage rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/environmental-rules#TOC-Table:-Damage-from-Falling-Objects) so I ruled no, but after finding and reading them I'm thinking I'm wrong. This has led me to a couple related questions.

1. Would he take fall damage while pouncing from a high position?
2. Would he deal falling damage while pouncing?
3. If both are true, is the falling damage and falling/landing damage counted together or separate for purposes of DR?
4. Would this all be the same if he was under the effect of a *fly* spell (and sufficiently up in the air) and pounced?

Comment: Okay, I think we can be done with flipflopping on the pronouns. The original post had a near-even split between he/him and they/them, with a slight numerical edge to he/him, so landing on he/him seems fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you take falling damage after a high jump of over 10 feet?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57271/do-you-take-falling-damage-after-a-high-jump-of-over-10-feet)

Comment: @DaleM What's the *Pathfinder 1E* relevance of that *D&D 5E* question?

Comment: Voting to leave open as the dupe target is for D&D5e, not P1e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be well-covered under the rules, but here's how I'd rule.

I don't think it's a good idea to let characters use the Falling Objects rules, because (1) a character is not an inanimate object, and (2) characters falling from a great height take a lot more damage than objects do.

However, we can take this sentence from the Falling Objects rules as a baseline:

> Note that a falling object takes the same amount of damage as it deals.

So, what I'd rule is: the kitty takes falling damage for falling 30 feet (3d6, with modifiers for falling deliberately and for Acrobatics check).  The creature being attacked takes the same 3d6 as the kitty, but doesn't get to make an Acrobatics check to reduce the damage.  This damage gets applied on the first successful melee attack made as part of the pounce.

Note that anyone who takes real (not subdual) damage from a fall is knocked prone.  It seems fair to rule that this happens to both characters.

As to the Fly spell: we don't have a lot of precedent in D&D for dealing damage by moving at someone very fast and colliding with them.  If a wizard cast Expeditious Retreat, and wanted to injure a foe by running into them, I would probably look at them funny.  If that same wizard then cast Fly, and wanted to injure a foe by running into them from above, that wouldn't work any better for me.

Comment: Crashing into a foe--if not reskinned as a simple charge--is usually either an attempt to bull rush, overrun, or, for some foes, trample. Letting creatures damage foes by falling on them means suicide songbird zombies become, like, *really dangerous.*

Comment: @HeyICanChan dude, songbird zombies are *already* really dangerous.  Dropping objects is ranged touch to hit. A Bayonet dropped from 150 ft by a duck is a -2 (net) ranged touch attack dealing 6d6 damage.  And a duck can easily carry 3 bayonets while flying.  Beware the Iron Wings :P

Comment: Our current summoner enjoys summoning creatures in the air and dropping them on foes. It's very effective.

Comment: @GreySage Psst! ["A creature... brought into being or transported to your location by a conjuration spell cannot appear... floating in an empty space. It must arrive in an open location on a surface capable of supporting it."](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Conjuration) I know, right? Don't worry. I won't tell the GM.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing pounce without fly or a jump check in this situation is a houserule.  It does, however, make a lot of sense and I recommend continuing to do so.

1. Yes; he has fallen more than 10 feet.
2. No, but he may deal [falling object damage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/environmental-rules#TOC-Falling-Objects) if he is an object, or deal such damage indirectly if he is attending any objects.
3. Each object's falling damage should be reduced separately.  If he *is* an object, however, the damage he himself takes from falling as a creature and from falling as an object should probably be summed before they are reduced by DR.
4. Nope! Instead:

   1. No; he has moved 10 feet, but he is flying not falling
   2. No; he is flying, not falling

Note that most flying characters can *choose* to fall instead, if they'd like, and some special creatures have special 'diving charge'-like abilities that give extra bonuses for charging down at least 10 feet from the air. [Example](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/monstrous-humanoids/maftet)

Comment: Pounce is a type of charge, and since you can charge while flying, burrowing, or swimming.... I saw no reason why other variants of charge would not be allowed.

Comment: Oh, sure, but you can't charge while falling, technically, because falling is forced movement; it's not your move.

Comment: @Fering Unless Paizo's finally written its own [burrowing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/movement) rules, creatures, while burrowing, can't charge.

Comment: "Allowing pounce without fly or a jump [*Note:* Acrobatics?] check in this situation is a house rule." Citation?

Comment: @HeyICanChan interesting.  When you make a acrobatics check to jump, I normally call that a Jump Check, but I did play 3.5 pre-pathfinder so that may be just me.  Is this non-standard usage?  Also, do you want a citation for being able to use Acrobatics/jumping to move through the air or a citation for falling movement not being a part of your normal movement or for fly speeds letting you charge or what?  I make a lot of claims there, but they're all (from my POV) common knowledge, so I'm not sure what you would like citing on.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with *any* use of pounce specifically *mandating* a skill check. I mean, sure, the GM could ask for an Acrobatics check to determine distance jumped, but I don't know what any other check would be *for.*